# getting error when trying to get average rating Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rating' of null

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two collections recipes and reviews and users can review a recipe and can rate it from 1 to 5 and i am trying to get the average rating of recipe but getting error **Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rating' of null**
Can you please guide me what mistake i am making and how to solve it.

**collections.js**

```
Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');
Reviews = new Mongo.Collection('reviews');
```

**add_review.js**

```
Template.add_review.events({
    'submit .add-review':function(event){
        var rating = event.target.rating.value;
        var review = event.target.review.value;
            Reviews.insert({
                rating:rating,
                review:review,
                recipeId:Router.current().data()._id
            });

        return false;
})
```

**helper to get average rating**

```
Template.reviews.helpers({

    averageRating: function() {
        var reviews = Reviews.find({recipeId: Router.current().data()._id});
        var ratings = _.pluck(reviews, 'rating');
        var sum = ratings.reduce(function(pv, cv){return pv + cv;}, 0);
        var avg = sum / ratings.length;
        return Math.round(avg);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) returns a cursor. In order for reviews to be an array, you'll need to use [fetch](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) like this:

```
var reviews = Reviews.find({recipeId: Router.current().data()._id}).fetch();
```

Also note that you'll need to guard against the case where ratings is an empty array. In that situation your average will return `Infinity`. Maybe something like:

```
Template.reviews.helpers({
  averageRating: function() {
      var selector = {recipeId: Router.current().data()._id};
      var reviews = Reviews.find(selector).fetch();

      if (reviews.length === 0)
        return 0;

      var ratings = _.pluck(reviews, 'rating');
      var sum = ratings.reduce(function(pv, cv){return pv + cv;}, 0);
      var avg = sum / ratings.length;
      return Math.round(avg);
  }
});
```

Recommended reading: [meteor common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: It worked for me and very good suggestion to return 0 if reviews length is 0. just one important thing to add that _.pluck will return array of strings so i used parseInt to convert them into integers. I found your blog is great for Meteors developers and you have covered very unique  topics.So please write more about Meteor so beginners like me keep benefiting from this blog.   @David Weldon